# How do i access data after model.add(Flatten()) layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, xgboost

I am trying to use CNN for feature extraction and XGboost for classification of a image data. I researched and found that it could be done by extracting the data after the convolution layers. I found some source code for similar problem and tried on my own.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation="relu", input_shape = data.shape[1:])) 
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu") )
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2))) #max pool window 2x2

model.add(Flatten()) 

model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", name='firstDenseLayer'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

# model.summary()

# print(model)

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(data, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data, val_label))
```

Below i accessed the dense layer named "firstDenseLayer".

```
import xgboost as xgb
from keras.models import Model

layerName = 'firstDenseLayer'

intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layerName).output)

intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data) 


from xgboost import XGBClassifier

xgbmodel = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', num_class= 2)
xgbmodel.fit(intermediate_output, label)
```

```
xgbmodel.score(intermediate_output, label)
```

As i am new in this, i have several confusions.

1. How the data is being flowed. After i extract the features of the pictures via convolution layers, how do i actually access the data from there?
2. What is this line of code doing? What data is it extracting?

```
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

3. When i omit(keep commented out) the below line,

```
model.fit(data, label, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data, val_label))
```

from the first snippet and run the XGboost model directly the XGboost gives low accuracy and when i don't it gives higher accuracy. Why is it being like that?

Kindly help me out. I am stuck with this for quite a while. I am just trying to access the extracted features data from the last convolution layer and use that data to do classification using XGboost. As i tried to follow the method that i found from online, i am not sure if it is the the only way of doing it. If there is another way kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The `model.fit(...)` line does what you would expect, it trains the convnet defined by `model` on some data and labels. Your classifier yielding lower accuracy when you're using randomly initialized weights (i.e. without running `fit`) is not surprising.

`intermediate_layer_model` is constructed as a keras model whose output is the dense layer just before the output of `model`. Note the `name` parameter given to the dense layer in the construction of `model`.
You could just as easily give a name to one of the `Conv2D` layers and access it the same way. Alternatively, you could store the layer in a python variable, i.e. instead of

```
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu"))
```

in the model construction it could say

```
last_conv_layer = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation="relu")
model.add(last_conv_layer)
```

Then for the `intermediate_layer_model` you put

```
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=last_conv_layer.output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears a lot. Can you kindly explain what data is being extracted via this code? `intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data) `

Comment: When `intermediate_layer_model` is being defined, there is an `inputs` and `outputs` param. The `inputs` param is taken as `model.input`, the `outputs` param is `some_layer.output`. What this means is on a `predict` call you can put in the same type of data you would use with `model` and get back whatever `some_layer` would yield when using `model.predict` on the same data